# How to enter multiple users

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have a question for you guys and I'm hoping you may be able to shed some light onto my situation. Currently, I am making a project and needing some help. We have no book to use, so it was hard to come this far not knowing anything about the matter. I've been trying for weeks and couldn't get what I needed so I finally decided to ask for help

I am currently trying to build a form, that will allow me to enter a user, and display the information into a text area. I can do that, but I have to be able to store more than just one person example is below [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBn9y.png). currently mine can only hold one user. I'm not really good with arrays and don't know much about them.

Can anybody help? This is my only option to figuring it out because I don't know what to do from here.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
  var memberArray = [name, birthday, gender];

  function myFunction() {
    var name = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value;
    var birthday = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[1].value;
    var gender = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[2].value;
  }

  function displayMembers() {
    var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = x;
    var y = document.getElementById("birthday").value;
    document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = y;
    var z = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = z;
    var finish = [x, y, z];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      finish[i] + ",";
    }
    document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = finish;
  }

  function reset() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset()
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Create an array of users. And not having a book is hardly something that should slow down someone in this day and age. You clearly have internet access.

Comment: You don’t need that `for` loop. Simply use `finish.join(",")`.

Comment: Each `document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML =` line is _overwriting_ the previous value because you’re assigning a new value every time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to create what you want.

The most important aspect is separation of concerns, so you don't depend on the html to remember your members for you.

```js
//A list of members
var members = [];

//Adding a member. Notice how it doesn't care about the DOM
function addMemberFunction(name, birthday, gender) {
  //Add the new member as an object to the list
  members.push({
    name: name,
    birthday: birthday,
    gender: gender
  })
}

//DOM
function drawMembers() {
    //Get out list
    var list = document.getElementById("members");
    //Empty list
    list.innerHTML = '';
    //For each member
    for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
      var member = members[i];
      //Add list item
      list.innerHTML += '<li>' +
        //Accessing the current member object
        member.name +
        ' (' +
        member.gender +
        '), ' +
        member.birthday.getFullYear() +
        '</li>';
    }
  }
  //reset dom function

function reset() {
    document.getElementById("name").value = '';
    document.getElementById("day").value = '1';
    document.getElementById("month").value = '1';
    document.getElementById("year").value = '2016';
    document.getElementById("gender").checked = false;
  }
  //Listen for create
document.getElementById("createMember")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    //Add member
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var birthday = new Date(
      document.getElementById("year").value +
      '-' +
      document.getElementById("month").value +
      '-' +
      document.getElementById("day").value
    );
    var gender = document.getElementById("gender").checked ? "male" : "female";
    addMemberFunction(name, birthday, gender);
    //Reset form
    reset();
    //Draw result
    drawMembers();
  }, false)

//Listen for reset
document.getElementById("resetMember")
  .addEventListener("click", reset, false)

//Start
drawMembers();
```

```html
<div id="addMemberControls">
  <p>Name:
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" title="Name" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>Birthday:
    <input type="number" min="1" max="31" id="day" placeholder="Day" title="Day" value="1" />
    <input type="number" min="1" max="12" id="month" placeholder="Month" title="Month" value="1" />
    <input type="number" min="1900" max="2020" id="year" placeholder="Year" title="Year" value="2016" />
  </p>
  <p>Gender:(check for male)
    <input id="gender" type="checkbox" />
  </p>
  <button id="createMember">Create member</button>
  <button id="resetMember">Reset</button>
</div>
<ol id="members">

</ol>
```